# String to float unusual split

Tags: java, bluetooth, inputstream, esp32

I am trying to receive data through serial bluetooth communication using esp32 with android. The problem occurs when i convert the received string to float.
I am converting String to float using the following function

```
float ParseFloat(String strNumber) {

    if (strNumber != null ) {
        try {

            return Float.parseFloat(strNumber);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return -1;   
        }
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Instead of getting the full string. The first character(digit) of the string is taken as a separate string

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. A couple things: (1) please tag your question with the programming language you're using, (2) please refrain from posting images of code, paste the code into your question and [format it into a codeblock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) instead. Thanks.

Comment: it is not likely the problem is the conversion. You probably have a non-printable character in your string. Or, you need to wait for the rest of the string to arrive.

Comment: i am just using numbers in my string.